# How to ignore JsonPropertyNameAttribute annotation when serialize object?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net, system.text.json

I want to deserialize JSON from other guys API which uses different naming policy, so  I add `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` to POCO

```cs
public class X
{
  [JsonPropertyNameAttribute("uid")]
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and it expected it to be serialized to

```
{
  "name" : xx,
  .....
}
```

or

```
{ 
  "Name" : xx,
  .....
}
```

not

```
{
  "uid" : xx,
  ......
}
```

How to do it with `System.Text.Json` gracefully?
*(except creating new POCO like X without annotation)*

Comment: currently, my simplest way to do this is using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your model without JsonPropertyNameAttribute

```
public class X
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create cutsom policy

```
public class DeserializePolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name)
        => name == "Name" ? "uid" : name;
}
```

Use it to deserialize

```
string text = "{\"uid\":\"abc\"}";

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = new DeserializePolicy() };

var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<X>(text, options);
```

Serialize without policy

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<X>(x);
```

I'm not sure if this can be considered gracefully.

Comment: thanks, it is gracefullly, but when it happens in a lot of renaming properties and a lot of POCO, seems lengthiness。